# C# XML Serialization for UWP and Xamarin with xsd.exe or svcutil.exe

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xamarin, uwp

I got an relative complex xml file, which i want to use as a template for my serialization and deserialization. Because it might change and grow over time, i kinda hoped that i could rely on the generation of the code via **xsd.exe** or **svcutil.exe**.
But sadly iam not able to get it working easily inside **Xamarin** AND **UWP**. UWP doesnt seem to support the default xml stuff, so i had to go with svcutil.exe to get a file with DataContract-Attributes.

The problem is in Xamarin the **System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlSerializableServices.AdDefaultSchema()** method is missing and in UWP the whole class **System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlSerializableServices** is missng.

Is there a way to automatically generate the code for Xamarin and UWP?
If not what would be another way to achieve a easy way of parsing an xml in both systems or should i just do it by myself?

Comment: Why not use the [`XmlReader`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Xml.XmlReader)?

Comment: If there would be changes to the xsd, i could automaticallly generate the models again for serialization and deserialization. Else i would have to adjust the xsd, do the parsing partly myself and adjust the models aswell. Atleast thats how i see it at the moment.

Comment: Are you asking for a method to programmatically generate class model for your complex xml file in xamarin?

Comment: Well actually i was looking for a way to create them both for xamarin and uwp. And actually it works with the xsd.exe. Posting answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer in the following post:

[how can i use the file that is generated by xsd.exe in windows 10 universal app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34411441/how-can-i-use-the-file-that-is-generated-by-xsd-exe-in-windows-10-universal-app)

I just use now the xsd.exe to create a *.cs file with the models, which works fine for xamarin without any extra work. For the uwp project, i just link the file now from the other project and added some "dummy" code, like in the post above.

```
namespace System
{
    internal class SerializableAttribute : Attribute
    {
    }
}
namespace System.ComponentModel
{
    internal class DesignerCategoryAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public DesignerCategoryAttribute(string _) { }
    }
}
```

It seems to work fine that way and means if there will be changes to the xsd, i just can generate a new *.cs file with the models and dont have to handle the changes by myself.